# Upload file not working when I add a function

Tags: php

This code uploads a file to a certain directory. Now I want to add file name checker to avoid overwriting.
I created a function that returns `randomString_filename` if the file name has a duplicate and also return exact file name if duplicate(s) weren't existed. This is the function written in PHP:

```
function rnmFile($dir,$flname){
    foreach (glob("$dir*.*") as $filename) {
        if ($filename == $flname){
            $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $randomString = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
                $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
            }
            return $randomString.'_'.$flname;
        }
        else {
            return $flname;
        }

    }
}
```

and this is the file upload code:

```
session_start();
$table_name = $_SESSION['un'];
if (!is_dir($table_name)) {
    mkdir($table_name);
}
$output_dir = $table_name . '/';
if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
    $ret = array();

    $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
    {
        if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
        {
            $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
            echo "<br> Error: ".$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
            $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$fileName;
        }
        else
        {
            $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
            for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
            {
                $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
                $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$fileName;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName );
            }
        }

    }
    echo json_encode($ret);
```

Whenever I add the function, the file upload seems not to work and I don't know why.
This is how I add the function to the code:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.rnmFile($output_dir,$fileName));
$ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.rnmFile($output_dir,$fileName);
```

and applies to the rest.
Btw, this is the code that access the file upload

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="mulitplefileuploader">Upload!</div>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function()
        {

            var settings = {
                url: "upload_logic.php",
                method: "POST",
                allowedTypes:"jpg,png,gif,doc,pdf,zip",
                fileName: "myfile",
                multiple: true,
                onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
                {
                    $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is success</font>");
                },
                onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
                {
                    $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is Failed</font>");
                }
            }
            $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);

        });
    </script>
</div>
```

It also uses jQuery upload plugin

Comment: how did you debug the code so far? did you try writing comments to see how the executing is happening or where exactly the code is failing? you should put debug statements where ever you suspect the code can go wrong, and if it  requires you to write debug statement each and every line of the code then you should do that.

Comment: I added `echo some_codes_for_debugging` but It isn't displaying.  
I also tried adding `print_r` also not displaying errors

Comment: it is difficult to understand you say echo some_for_for_debugging, as a start What you need to do is print all the values from top to bottom of script(well, at least where you feel it is necessary) then see "which" exact value is not printing, that will give you a hint to the problem

Comment: @XtraCode `the file upload seems not to work` Where exactly it does not work? Does the PHP code inside `if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))` get executed?

Comment: Yes, but when I try adding the function, It doesn't work anymore

Comment: @XtraCode What function are you adding and where? Are you talking about `print_r`? Try using `error_log` or `trigger_error` function just to write some data to your `php_error` file.

Comment: `$out_dir` is undefined, I assume it should be `$output_dir`?

Comment: I'm taking about my function. The `rnmFile()` function

Comment: you tried whether the `rnmFile()` works seperatly using some data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, gonna answer my own question.
The variable `$fileName` is also accessed by `jquery.uploadfile.min.js` so I took advantage of it and used it as my variable. I also removed some useless codes and replace `glob()` function with `file_exsist()`. This is the code that is working right now

```
<?php
session_start();
$table_name = $_SESSION['un'];
if (!is_dir($table_name)) {
    mkdir($table_name);
}
$output_dir = $table_name . '/';

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
    function rnmFile($dir,$flname){

            if (file_exists($dir.$flname)){
                $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                $randomString = '';
                for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
                    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
                }
                return $randomString.'_'.$flname;
            }
            else {
                return $flname;
            }

        }
    }

            $fileName = rnmFile($output_dir,$_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.''.$fileName);
?>
```